# JAVA; When The string from the file is printed on screen null is also printed along with it at the end

Tags: java

Soo my program is working...but there is just one problem...null is also being printed along with the content or string from the file... is there anyway i can stop null from being printed. The code read asks a user to give a filename .txt then the user is asked a the character he/she wold like to be searched and the program searches for the that specified character in the string , prints out the content of the text file and tells how many times it was found. The problem is after it prints out the contents of the text file (string) it also prints oout the word null but null is not in the txt file.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;

public class filefinder
 {
   public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
   {


         //needed for scanner class
          Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);

          int charCount = 0;
            String filename = "";
            String str = "";
            String line = "";
            boolean isString = false;
            boolean fileFound = false;
            FileReader freader;

          // get users string
            while (!fileFound)
            {
          while (!isString)
            {   
            try { Thread.currentThread().sleep(500); }
                catch ( Exception e ) { }

            System.out.println("Please enter a filename: ");
            System.out.println("");
          filename = kb.nextLine();
            if (filename != null)
                   isString = true;
           }//end inner while loop

            // open file
            try 
            {
                freader = new FileReader(filename);     

            fileFound = true;


            Thread.currentThread().sleep(1500);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {

            System.out.println("");
            System.out.println("The system cannot find the file specified.");
            System.out.println("");
            isString = false;


            }//end try-catch
            }//end outer while loop

            try { Thread.currentThread().sleep(1000); }
          catch ( Exception e ) { }

           freader = new FileReader(filename);
            BufferedReader inputFile = new BufferedReader(freader);

            // Read first line from file
            while (line !=null)
            {

            line = inputFile.readLine();

            if (line != null)


            try { Thread.currentThread().sleep(1000); }
          catch ( Exception e ) { }

                 str = str+ "\n" + line; 
            }//end while

            System.out.println(str);

            inputFile.close();

          // get users character
            System.out.println("");
          System.out.println("Please enter a character you want to find: ");
            System.out.println("");
          char userChar = kb.nextLine().charAt(0);






                    while(str.length()>0){
                    for(int i= 0;i<str.length();i++){
                                if(str.charAt(i)==userChar)
                        charCount++;

                }


          System.out.println("\n The entered character " +"\"" + userChar +
                              "\"  inside  " + filename +
                              "was found " + charCount +   " times.\n");         
                                      break;  

        }
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

This is the problem:

```
  while (line !=null)
  {

  line = inputFile.readLine();

  if (line != null)


  try { Thread.currentThread().sleep(1000); }
catch ( Exception e ) { }

       str = str+ "\n" + line; 
  }
```

It's hard to tell exactly what you think that means because the indentation is so poor, but it's equivalent to this:

```
while (line !=null)
{  
    line = inputFile.readLine();
    if (line != null)
    {
        try { Thread.currentThread().sleep(1000); }
        catch ( Exception e ) { }
    }
    str = str+ "\n" + line; 
}
```

In other words, you're still concatenating `line` in the loop whether or not it's null; you're just not *sleeping* if it's null. I suspect you *wanted* it to be this:

```
while (line !=null)
{  
    line = inputFile.readLine();
    if (line != null)
    {
        try { Thread.currentThread().sleep(1000); }
        catch ( Exception e ) { }
        str = str+ "\n" + line; 
    }
}
```

I *strongly* recommend that:

- You get your IDE to perform indentation for you so you can *clearly* see what's covered by an `if` block etc
- You *always* use braces for while/if/etc, again to make things clearer
- You don't catch bare `Exception` (catch a more specific one)
- You don't *swallow* exceptions without logging them
- You don't sleep for a second at a time for no particular reason
- You don't use string concatenation in a loop ([use `StringBuffer`/`StringBuilder` instead](http://pobox.com/~skeet/java/stringbuffer.html))
- You break up your code into smaller methods
- You declare local variables at the point of first use, rather than all at the top of the method
- You close streams and other similar resources in `finally` blocks to avoid leaking resources in the case of an exception being thrown

Comment: Ahhh ok so my code style prevents me from analyzing properly thank you so much.. I wil have to indent now..I am using Jgrasp

Comment: I think your recommendations are good; however, please consider the use of the word `You` as it may not be as well received as intended.

Comment: @losthorse: In what way? These are applicable to any reader. I'm perfectly happy with it...

Answer (score 1):

The essential loop is

```
String str = "";
while (line != null) {
    line = inputFile.readLine();
    str = str + "\n" + line;
}// end while

System.out.println(str);
```

This will read all lines until the last one. But since the check for end-of-file (i.e. `line==null`) is made inside the while-criterion, also the `null` line will be appended to your `str` variable.

Comment: so i should remove it from the while  crietrtion?

Comment: You can do as Jon proposed in his answer.